# Visual Studio Code Extension Development - How to override top menu F5 deployment

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are developing a VS Code extension where we have added custom commands for `F5` using the `app.json` configuration, as documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.keybindings. We have a custom language server implementing the LSP: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/.

Our `F5` command is also for debugging, but we need to do some stuff before in the local environment, such as building the latest source. Only then we send the debug request to our language server.

This works fine when using the `F5` shortcut and using the command palette, but when using the "top menu" our command implementation for `F5` is bypassed:

[image]

Is there any support in the extension development API to override this to use our custom command instead of directly issuing the debug request to the language server?